# vue select field get keypress value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete

I'm using vue-search-select for implementing autocomplete on select field. Now I want to get the input user enter to search from select field. I tried using keyup event but didn't work. Is there any way to get that input user enter?

```
<model-list-select
 :list="activity_list"
 v-model="business_activity"
 option-value="id"
 :custom-text="optiontext"
 @input="onChange($event)"
 @keyup="keyhandle($event)"
>
</model-list-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `@keyup="keyhandle($event)"` with `@keyup.enter="keyhandle($event)"`

Comment: make sure your method name is correct - `keyhadle` is misspelled. Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: no that was misspell here. I'm trying to console but the function didn't get called on any keypress

Comment: I've tried to re-create this issue in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wright-znw2g?file=/src/App.vue and it seems that event are not being fired. Only way is to use watcher on your model property (in this case "business_activity" to get new and old value.